# opacity in a speech bubble in css

Tags: css, opacity

I'm using http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/ to do a speech bubble, I want the inside of the bubble and the triangle to have a background with an opacity of 0.7.

For the background I'm using:
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

and for the triangle:
opacity:0.7;

But it seems that the triangle and the background doesn't have the same opacity, I put a higher z-index to the triangle but it doesn't help.

My full css are:

```
.infoBubble {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    padding:6px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
}

.infoBubble:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-6px;
    left:20px; 
    opacity:0.7;
    border-width:6px 6px 0; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000 transparent;
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/QzQzW/

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your opacity of the main bubble is not being applied - your three styles:

```
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:-o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:linear-gradient(#000, #000);
```

are overwriting the

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QzQzW/1/

also if you use

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
```

instead of

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
```

it will make your shadow work properly

http://jsfiddle.net/QzQzW/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.infoBubble {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    padding:6px;
    background: #000;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.infoBubble:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-6px;
    left:20px; 
    opacity:0.7;
    border-width:6px 6px 0; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000 transparent;
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-that-perfect solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/QzQzW/2/

Below listing the changed part:

```css
.infoBubble {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /*
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background:linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    */
}
.infoBubble:after {
/*  opacity:0.7;*/
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) transparent;
}
```

I changed `0.7` to `0.5` only to outstand contrast. You can of course change it back to `0.7`.

The reason I commented out your `linear-gradient`, is that it's considered `background-image`, so the `background-color` value might get "override".

And I commented out your `opacity:0.7` since the triangle is made up of `border`, not any content or background, so I put that alpha into `border-color`.

The downside of this solution is that `box-shadow` seems to always stay on top of any `::before` and `::after` pseudo-element, no matter what `z-index` I give.