# Pure CSS speech bubble with semi-transparent background and a border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'd like to create a speech bubble using pure CSS.

There's a few requirements I have:

- It must scale with either the content + some padding or a preffered size.
- It's background color should be semi-transparent.
- You should be able to set a border, with it's own level of transparency.
- You should be able to set a border-radius, which both the border and background adheres to.

Here's an example of what I would imagine two of such a speech bubble would look like, the first has a preffered with and height and centers the content, the second fits the height and width of the content with some padding. I think the crucial bit here is that in both cases, the little pointy triangle remains the same size and is centered.
[image]

I've tried looking for different speech bubble approaches, and attempted to adapt examples, such as #34 on the list [here](https://css-generators.com/tooltip-speech-bubble/):

```css
/* HTML: <div class="tooltip">This is a Tooltip with a border and a border radius. Border can have a solid or gradient coloration and the background is transparent</div> */
.tooltip {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 28ch;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff000055;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.tooltip {
    /* triangle dimension */
    --a: 90deg; /* angle */
    --h: 1em; /* height */

    --p: 50%; /* triangle position (0%:left 100%:right) */
    --b: 7px; /* border width */
    --r: 1.2em; /* the radius */

    padding: 1em;
    color: #415462;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0;
    background: conic-gradient(#4ecdc4 33%, #fa2a00 0 66%, #cf9d38 0); /* your coloration */
    --_p: clamp(
        var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) + var(--b),
        var(--p),
        100% - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) - var(--b)
    );
}
.tooltip:before {
    padding: var(--b);
    border-radius: var(--r) var(--r) min(var(--r), 100% - var(--p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2))
        min(var(--r), var(--p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2)) / var(--r);
    background-size: 100% calc(100% + var(--h));
    clip-path: polygon(
        0 100%,
        0 0,
        100% 0,
        100% 100%,
        calc(var(--_p) + var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) - var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4)) 100%,
        calc(var(--_p) + var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) - var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4))
            calc(100% - var(--b)),
        calc(var(--_p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) + var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4))
            calc(100% - var(--b)),
        calc(var(--_p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) + var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4)) 100%
    );
    -webkit-mask:
        linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
        linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
}
.tooltip:after {
    bottom: calc(-1 * var(--h));
    clip-path: polygon(
        calc(var(--_p) + var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2)) calc(100% - var(--h)),
        var(--_p) 100%,
        calc(var(--_p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2)) calc(100% - var(--h)),
        calc(var(--_p) - var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) + var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4))
            calc(100% - var(--h) - var(--b)),
        var(--_p) calc(100% - var(--b) / sin(var(--a) / 2)),
        calc(var(--_p) + var(--h) * tan(var(--a) / 2) - var(--b) * tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4))
            calc(100% - var(--h) - var(--b))
    );
}
```

But setting a semi-transparent background color (and a border-radius to hide the overflow behind the border) doesn't fill in the little triangle at the bottom. Nor could I find a way to do so.

I also found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144960/speech-bubble-with-triangle-translucent-background) which suggests an approach which I adapted to the code below

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="bubble">
  <p>
    Hello world! I am some content. Who's got time for lorems?
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.background {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bubble {
  height: fit-content;
  color: red;
  max-width: 75%;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 12px 0 12px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  margin-top:40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top:0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #0000bb55;
}

.bubble::before,
.bubble::after{
  
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  top: -21px;
  border:1px solid;
  background: #0000bb55;
}
.bubble::before {
  right:-1px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:skew(-45deg);
}
.bubble::after{
  left:-1px;
  border-width:1px 0 0 1px;
  border-radius:4px 0 0 0;
}

p {
 margin-top:0;
}
```

But as soon as you start introducing semi-transparent colors, those skewed transforms start overlapping and introducing color discrepancies.

[image]

Finally, the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356438/opacity-in-a-speech-bubble-in-css) post also seems to have different opacity levels for the triangle and the background:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="infoBubble">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: pink;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.infoBubble {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    padding:6px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
 }

.infoBubble:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-6px;
    left:20px; 
    opacity:0.7;
    border-width:6px 6px 0; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) transparent;
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

So, I am wondering.. what is the right approach here?

Comment: do you want the tail to be only at the center? and fixed size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems my collection doesn't contain that case but we can achieve it by combining #37 with #21 https://css-generators.com/tooltip-speech-bubble/

First you copy the code of #37, then you add an extra span that will contain the code of #21 (not all its code but only the pseudo element part)

```css
.tooltip {
  /* triangle dimension */
  --a: 90deg; /* angle */
  --h: 1em; /* height */

  --p: 50%; /* triangle position (0%:left 100%:right) */
  --b: 7px; /* border width */
  --r: 1.2em; /* the radius */
  --c1: #0009; /* semi-transparent background*/
  --c2: red; /* border color*/

  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: conic-gradient(var(--c2) 0 0);
  --_p:clamp(var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) + var(--b),var(--p),100% - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) - var(--b));
}
.tooltip:before {
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r) var(--r) min(var(--r),100% - var(--p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2)) min(var(--r),var(--p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2))/var(--r);
  background-size: 100% calc(100% + var(--h));
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%,0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,
    calc(var(--_p) + var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) - var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) 100%,
    calc(var(--_p) + var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) - var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) calc(100% - var(--b)),
    calc(var(--_p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) + var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) calc(100% - var(--b)),
    calc(var(--_p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) + var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) 100%
  );
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}
.tooltip:after {
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--h));
  clip-path: polygon(
    calc(var(--_p) + var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2)) calc(100% - var(--h)),
    var(--_p) 100%,
    calc(var(--_p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2)) calc(100% - var(--h)),
    calc(var(--_p) - var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) + var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) calc(100% - var(--h) - var(--b)),
    var(--_p) calc(100% - var(--b)/sin(var(--a)/2)),
    calc(var(--_p) + var(--h)*tan(var(--a)/2) - var(--b)*tan(45deg - var(--a)/4)) calc(100% - var(--h) - var(--b)));
}
.tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, min(100% - var(--b), var(--p) + var(--h)* tan(var(--a) / 2) - var(--b)* tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4)) calc(100% - var(--b)), var(--p) calc(100% + var(--h) - var(--b) / sin(var(--a) / 2)), max(var(--b), var(--p) - var(--h)* tan(var(--a) / 2) + var(--b)* tan(45deg - var(--a) / 4)) calc(100% - var(--b)));
  background: var(--c1) content-box;
  border-image: conic-gradient(var(--c1) 0 0) fill 0 / calc(100% - var(--h) - var(--b)) max(var(--b), 100% - var(--p) - var(--h)* tan(var(--a) / 2)) 0 max(var(--b), var(--p) - var(--h)* tan(var(--a) / 2)) / 0 0 var(--h) 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/800/600) center/cover
}

.tooltip {
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 28ch;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
<span></span>
This is a Tooltip with a border and a border radius. Border can have a solid or gradient coloration and the background is transparent</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I think I should be able to figure out how to combine the other examples should I want the tail to be positioned somewhere else.